# Getting last cell to be inserted and the next empty cell in excel using vb2010

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

```
xlwsheet.Cells(10, 2) = SearchedID.ToString
        xlwsheet.Cells(11, 2) = Name.ToString
        xlwsheet.Cells(12, 2) = ""
        xlwsheet.Cells(13, 2) = BlckYr.ToString
        For num1 = 0 To dgv1stSem.RowCount - 1
            For num2 = 0 To dgv1stSem.ColumnCount - 1
                For num3 = 1 To dgv1stSem.Columns.Count
                    Try
                        xlwsheet.Cells(17 + num1, 1 + num2) = dgv1stSem.Item(num2, num1).FormattedValue.ToString
                    Catch ex As Exception

                    End Try
                Next
            Next
        Next
        xlapp = Nothing
        xlwbook = Nothing
    End If
```

I am trying to export 4 datagridview to excel but I can only transfer 1 datagridview, how can I find the last cell and the next empty cell to start the next transfer for the second datagridview?

Comment: There is no need to "find" the last cell, just set up a running Row-Index at the beginning of your loops and increment it inside your last nested loop. When you set xlwsheet.Cells values, use the row index instead of using all that math.

Comment: Well, I also have a one word tag above the exported datagridview. Its like Org1Fees Then the datagridview.

Comment: Ok...then +1 the row index or initialize it equal to 1

Comment: I dont understand. Sorry

Comment: Last used row is `xlwsheet.UsedRange.Rows(xlwsheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row`

Comment: I put that code in below but when I pressed the button and the export began, the value I wanted to display are nowhere to be found.